# Is it possible to leave an entry in bundle product required and yet allow it to be zero

Tags: bundled-product

I need a product which has other subproducts with variable quantity (like a box of multiple X of different sorts of desired quantity, which you fill in a input field). So I created a bundle product to accomplish this. For all the sorts I added corresponding bundle subproducts, and chose "dropdown" as input type, and made every entry required. Since in every option there is only one product, it appears not as dropdown, but as plain text, which is what I need. So I get pretty much what I need except for one thing: when one puts a zero in quantity field and adds products to the cart, quantity is automatically set to one. I suppose it is due to every option being labeled as "required". So when I unset "required", first of all I get a dropdown with the options (whether to add product or not), which is undesired (I would prefer for a customer to set zero if they don't want to have a particular sort of the product). On top of that quantity input field gets disabled.

So what I wanted to ask is whether it is possible to keep options for every sort to be required and at the same time avert automatic quantity increment in case zero? Should I override cart model / some controller? Or alternatively, can I get same functionality with options not being "required"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use grouped products instead of bundles, they do exactly what you describe:

[image: example from sample data]

The customer can choose any qty for each of the simple products and they will be added to the cart.

There is one difference though: they show up as single simple products in the cart. But clicking them, you still land on the grouped product page, so you don't need to make them visible individually.